postgresql why using view is 25 slower than standard sql?
I have quite complex query (many nested views and unions). But there's final query, which i use - just 4 columns with one where.
And today i found something weird.
If I run select * FROM nested_view WHERE field1=1 AND field2=2 it runs 50 seconds.
But when I copy the view definition and add wheres, it runs only 2 seconds.
The result is of course exact the same.
Any ideas? I expected that view should be even a little faster - because engine doesn't have to parse the query, but slower? 25 times????
edit
If I run SELECT * FROM (_definition_of_nested_view_) AS a WHERE field1=1 AND field2=2 -
it tooks 48 sec - so it looks like whereing view isn't 'modyfing' the definition, but just filters the whole view (which can take a long, long time)....
I have to rethink using views...

Please provide EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output.

Do you always do it in that order?  If so, running the view needs to read the data from disk.  Then running the underlying query finds the data already in memory, because the previous view usage just did the work to put it there.

@LaurenzAlbe Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 40456. And this is just first explain....

Try to reduce the example to the minimum that still demonstrates the problem. You can post links to https://explain.depesz.com . Is the view defined with security_barrier = on? Is row-level security active?
